# Store dynamic list of objects into database: how to remove obsolete and insert new entities

Tags: java, jpa, caching, spring-data

My application generates a list of objects. Data for these objects are fetched from different services and should be changed time to time. Entities that application fetches have not any IDs, so I can manipulate only with a couple of text fields. Generated list (generation takes near an hour and will be much slower in the future) should be represented to user, so I'd like to store it in database, no matter SQL or NoSQL (I can use MongoDB, MySQL or PostgreSQL).

How can I support database in actual state? I should update it after new list of entities generation: add new entities and delete those that stored in database but does not in the new list. I can not use something like [Apache Commons CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) to calculate difference between generated and stored in database lists, first of all this is bad solution, and  then I just haven't enough memory. Also I guess that generate query for each entity is bad solution (and how to find obsolete entities in that case?). But I'm sure that this problem could be solved using some framework without any own solution.

Is there any way to update database (add new entities and remove obsolete without any affect on actual entities) using Spring Data or any other framework? Also, I need to generate report with entities that was added to database.

Comment: Would you be so kind to clarify your question? Currently, all ORM frameworks (incl. Spring Data) support the update of the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ORM frameworks do provide these kind of features. ORM framworks mainly provides insert/merge function to which would satisfy your requirements.

insert() - It adds new records into database assigns primary key to each record.
merge() - it updates existing record or adds new record depending upon primary key, if it exists in Entity.